# Is there a way to retrieve Microsoft Project Gantt chart view data table cells font names programmatically?

Tags: winapi, ui-automation, ms-project, spy++, inspect.exe

I know that Microsoft Project Object model does't have any direct or indirect way to retrieve data table cells font names, I also tried third party project libraries (like Aspose.tasks) to see if they have functions to retrieve font names of cells at the intersection of each task and each column of a .mpp file but they seems to not have one either. I tried to export my workbook as a .xml file and search in its attributes but they didn't have font attributes either. I also tried to spend days questioning an A.I.
At last I thought maybe a help from a professional programmer can help me.

My guess is that this goal is achievable using Windows API functions somehow by passing the cells window handles to functions like GetWindowText(). The main problem for this approach is that cells windows in Microsoft Project's Gantt Chart View data table cells are not showing as a child windows in Spy++ (Unlike Inspect.exe that show them as seperate entities under their parent). Spy++ shows the last window related to gantt chart table's children as a 5 invisible windows that their class types are as follows: a ListBox, (a class type named "msctls_updown32" that makes scroll bars), two ComboBox classes and a Special MS Project class (a class called"JWinproj-GridClass"). I wonder how MSProject cells are made out of only these 5 window classes. As a note I also noticed that a similar structure is shown for Excel cells in Spy++ ,which you can't see a window for each of excel cells and instead you can see some classes which may Excel cells are made out of them.